# Converting website HTML to XML

Tags: python, html, xml

I have a [website](http://www.maldair.com/index.php/profile/view/2459) which I am trying to read for data, and have been trying without success to convert it to XML for easy reading.

So can someone help me convert it to XML in Python?

I have tried using the ElementTree module, LXML, BeautifulSoup (found on StackOverflow), all of which have not worked.

Comment: People here will as you " what exactly have you tried " so they can help. If you havent try the issue look around the website to see you can find an answer or just google it.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work here as that... Nobody will give you ready-to-go solution. Try something first and come back when you will have specific problem with XML parsing

Comment: what result do you expect ? HTML is easy reading - for human - when you open it in browser.

Comment: When I say easy reading I mean that I can easily navigate an xml file, I just need to get the html to be read as xml by python

Comment: Chilkat has an htmltoxml component that can do this.

Comment: Thanks, but after looking into chilkat, its payware and quite expensive as well so I can't use it

Comment: Convert it to XML - how? What do you want the XML to include?

Comment: I would like the HTML to be read like XML, because I can easily use the ElementTree module to navigate XML, so if the HTML is converted to XML I can read it. So as long as it finishes up at XML - I don't care whats in it, apart from the data